# how to select only Date and Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi i have a column having record **(2017-11-21 02:16:22.870)**.

I want select only Date and Hour (i.e:- 2017-11-21 02) from above records.

Comment: Define 2 computed columns in your query - one casting the existing column to date and one using the datepart function to get the hour.

Comment: do you mean you want to SELECT based on date and hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `datepart` for hour and `convert` for date

```
 select concat( concat(convert(date,'2017-11-21 02:16:22.870'),':'),  datepart(hour,'2017-11-21 02:16:22.870'))
```

2017-11-21:2

Comment: With all the DATETIME specific functionality in SQL Server, string manipulation of such data types is strongly frowned upon.  It involves all sorts of implicit datatype conversions, problems with server settings relating to region specific formatting, and generally just wastes available CPU cycles.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to round down by hour, you can do:

```
select dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, datetimecol), 0)
```

If you can live with two columns, I would recommend:

```
select cast(datetimecol as date) as datepart, datepart(hour, datetimecol) as hourpart
```

If you want the output in a particular format, you need to convert to a string:

```
select convert(varchar(13), datetimecol, 121)
```

Comment: Hi.. This  query output giving :- 2017-12-14 03:00:00.000 , but i want output as :- 2017-12-14 03   no minutes and seconds

Comment: @Sanjiv : That's like complaining that you want `1.5` and not `1.5000`.  The underlying value stored in the database is exactly the same, you're referring to the string representation, which is controlled by the presentation layer not the database.  SQL Server Management Studio may display it one way, a report display it another way, etc, etc.  But then you configure the presentation layer to display it how you want it.

Comment: @Sanjiv . . . Then you want to convert the value to a string.  That is not clear in the question; I modified the answer to address this.

Answer (score 2):

To select date from getdate() format

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, '2017-11-21 02:16:22.870')--2017-11-21
```

and select hour from getdate() format

```
 datepart(HOUR, '2017-11-21 02:16:22.870')--2
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use `CONVERT()` :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(13), col, 120)
```